# How to share referenced assemblies with other developers using TFS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am working on a VS2010 project with 4 other developers and we are having reference issues when we are connecting someone to the project for the first time or when somone adds a new dll file. How can we get the reference files to come from the bin folder on each developers machine when someone clicks on "Get latest Version" and "Check In"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [Nuget](http://nuget.org/) (preferable) or create a 'Lib' folder in the solution (and add it to source control) for referenced DLLs (third party or otherwise).

> NuGet is a Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to install and
>   update third-party libraries and tools in Visual Studio.

- [Using Nuget Packages](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/131917/using-nuget-packages/)
- [Managing NuGet Packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/Managing-NuGet-Packages-Using-The-Dialog)

There is an official Entity Framework Nuget package (as well as many others).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not only the 3rd party dlls that are the problem. Even the reference for "Entity framework" is different on some machines so there are issues when they try to build the app. I can copy all my dlls from the bin folder to their machine and it works fine then

Comment: Use Nuget then. Manually copying DLLs from a BIN folder is bonkers! :)

Comment: Yeah I know copying them is bonkers. I was wondering if there was a solution that would involve the TFS to handel this for you?

Comment: @WillNZ If you look at the references properties there is an option to copy-local. Setting it to true will copy the dll into the bin when you build. Also, look at the reference paths and make sure they're ambiguous (meaning something like C:\Project\SubDir\bin apposed to C:\Users\MyName\ThisPathWillNeverWorkNoMatterWhatIDo).

Comment: @WillNZ: Source control handles it for you with either of the methods I've suggested.

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for the answers. I was looking for an automated way of doing this without having to use NuGet to get the references. I will give @evanmcdonnal comment a try to see how it goes.